# dynamically setting textbox width using jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to dynamically change the width of the text box which displays the file name chosen in the file dialog since some of the filenames are quite long.
The code shown below does not change the size of the textbox (SelectedFile) I tried using width property as well but to no avail. Something seems to be overriding my changes.

Given the following html

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label class="input-group-btn">
        <span class="btn btn-primary">
            Browse&hellip; <input type="file" style="display: none;" >
        </span> 
    </label>
    <input id="SelectedFile" type="text" class="form-control" readonly >
</div>
```

And the following jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //attach the `fileselect` event to all file inputs on the page
            $(document).on('change', ':file', function () {
                var input = $(this),
                    numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
                    label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');

                input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
            });

            // Watch for our custom `fileselect` event
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(':file').on('fileselect', function (event, numFiles, label) {

                    var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
                        log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label,
                        fileLength = (label.length * 8) + 50;

                    if (input.length) {
                        input.val(log);
                    } else {
                        if (log) alert(log);
                    }
                    var newWidth = fileLength.toString() + 'px;';                        
                    $('#SelectedFile').css({ maxWidth: newWidth });
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('#SelectedFile').attr('style','width:'+ newWidth );` to set the width and have it change dynamically

```js
$(function () {
            //attach the `fileselect` event to all file inputs on the page
            $(document).on('change', ':file', function () {
                var input = $(this),
                    numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
                    label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');

                input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
            });

            // Watch for our custom `fileselect` event
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(':file').on('fileselect', function (event, numFiles, label) {

                    var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
                        log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label,
                        fileLength = (label.length * 8) + 50;

                    if (input.length) {
                        input.val(log);
                    } else {
                        if (log) alert(log);
                    }
                    var newWidth = fileLength.toString() + 'px;'; 
                    $('#SelectedFile').attr('style','width:'+ newWidth );
                });
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
    <label class="input-group-btn">
        <span class="btn btn-primary">
            Browse&hellip; <input type="file" style="display: none;" >
        </span> 
    </label>
    <input id="SelectedFile" type="text" class="form-control" readonly >
</div>
```

Comment: Well it works fine in your snippet, and that's how I first tried it, but it is NOT expanding my text box on my page

Answer (score 2):

**maxWidth** is only defining the max width an element can have.. it does not define the actual width, which is defined by the **width** property.

The textbox is contained inside an element with the class "input-group". The properties on the container may affect the children. It's difficult to say exactly why width is overridden without seeing your stylesheet.

Comment: I'm aware of the difference between the two, and that is noted in the post. I tried width first and thought the maxWidth was overriding so I tried resetting maxWidth. I'm using the standard bootstrap css style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Two things which worked for me:

1. `var newWidth = fileLength.toString() + 'px';`

Remove the ';' after 'px'

2. `$('#SelectedFile').css({ 'max-width': newWidth });`

It's the max-width property.